# none of my images or letters except my ComboBox are showing

Tags: java, graphics, combobox

I'm creating a hangman game and I have the body down but once I added the ComboBox none of that wants to show.
I've been looking over it for an hour and can't find out why! It should print out a full body and letters a-z. I've looked everywhere and can't find a solution. The code is pretty lengthy because I don't really know what's important or not. (Ignore the comments in the code just helps me)

```
public  class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener  {
     
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3919093956447306405L;
    static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 600;
    static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;
    static final int UNIT_SIZE = 100;
    static final int UNIT_SIZE2 = 19;
    static final int UNIT_SIZE3 = 40;
    static final int UNIT_SIZE4 = 20;
    static final int UNIT_SIZE5 = 60;
    // underline ^
    static final int UNIT_SIZE6 = (int) 7.5;
    // break between ___ fix ^
    static final int UNIT_SIZE7 = 0;
    // remove the image
    static final int GAME_UNITS = (SCREEN_WIDTH*SCREEN_HEIGHT)/UNIT_SIZE;
    Random random;
    int HeadX = 400;
    int HeadY = 100;  
    int BodyX = 430;
    int BodyY = 180;
    int Arm1X = 400;
    int Arm1Y = 240;
    int Arm2X = 460;
    int Arm2Y = 240;
    int Leg1X = 430;
    int Leg1Y = 300;
    int Leg2X = 451;
    int Leg2Y = 300;
    int Letter1UnderlineX = 0+ UNIT_SIZE6;
    int Letter1UnderlineY = 535;
    int Letter2UnderlineX = 75+ UNIT_SIZE6;
    int Letter2UnderlineY = 535;
    int Letter3UnderlineX = 150+ UNIT_SIZE6;
    int Letter3UnderlineY = 535;
    int Letter4UnderlineX = 225+ UNIT_SIZE6;
    int Letter4UnderlineY = 535;
    int Letter5UnderlineX = 300+ UNIT_SIZE6;
    int Letter5UnderlineY = 535;
    int Letter6UnderlineX = 375+ UNIT_SIZE6;
    int Letter6UnderlineY = 535;
    int Letter7UnderlineX = 450+ UNIT_SIZE6;
    int Letter7UnderlineY = 535;
    int Letter8UnderlineX = 525+ UNIT_SIZE6;
    int Letter8UnderlineY = 535;
    String a = ("a");
    String b = ("b");
    String c = ("c");
    String d = ("d");
    String e = ("e");
    String f1 = ("f");
    String g1 = ("g");
    String h = ("h");
    String i = ("i");
    String j = ("j");
    String k = ("k");
    String l = ("l");
    String m = ("m");
    String n = ("n");
    String o = ("o");
    String p = ("p");
    String q = ("q");
    String r = ("r");
    String s = ("s");
    String t = ("t");
    String u = ("u");
    String v = ("v");
    String w = ("w");
    String x = ("x");
    String y = ("y");
    String z = ("z");
     
    JFrame f;
     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 
    
        System.out.println("Welcome to Hang Man!");
        
            Start();    
        
            System.out.println("Test");
     
        

    }
    
     
    
    public static void Start(){
        
        Scanner YesNoScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner Letter = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] letters = new String[100];
        String ans = "";
        int count = 0;
         
        System.out.println("Would you like to play? (Yes - 1 | No - 2)");
          int YesNo = YesNoScanner.nextInt();
    if (YesNo == 1) {
        System.out.println("Rules: Word MUST be less than or equal to 8 characters \n \t No SPACES in the word or subject \n \t Don't show anyone the word if its your turn for the word ");
        System.out.println("You are about to start. \nDon't show anyone the word and subject your word is based off.");
        System.out.println("When writing the word only write ONE letter at a time!");
        System.out.println("Write 'done' when you are done writing your word.");

        
        

    System.out.println("\n\nChoose a word between 1-8 characters long\n ( ONE LETTER AT A TIME [press enter after every letter])");


    do {
        System.out.print("Letter " + (count + 1) + ": " ) ;
        ans = Letter.nextLine();
        if(!ans.equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {
            letters[count] = ans;
            count++;
    if (count == 8) {
        System.out.println("Maximium letters reached");
        ans = ("done");
        
    }
        }
        String one = letters[0];
    }while(!ans.equalsIgnoreCase ("done"));

    System.out.println("\nYour word is: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        System.out.print(letters[i]);
    }


    System.out.println(" \nIs this the word you would like? (Yes - 1 | No - 2)");





    }else {
        System.out.println("You chose to not play. Maybe later :C");
        System.exit(0);
    }
        

    Scanner YesNoScanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int YesNo2 = YesNoScanner2.nextInt();
    if (YesNo2 == 1) {
        SubjectWrite();
    }else {
        Start();
    }


    new GamePanel();

     
     




    }



    public static void SubjectWrite() {
        Scanner Subject = new Scanner(System.in);
        String ans = "";
        
        
        
        
        System.out.println("Please choose a subject! (1-10 characters long)");

        ans = Subject.nextLine();


        System.out.println(" \nIs this the Subject you would like? (Yes - 1 | No - 2)");
        System.out.println(ans);

        
        
        
        Scanner YesNoScanner3 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int YesNo3 = YesNoScanner3.nextInt();
        if (YesNo3 == 1) {
            System.out.println("Are you ready to play? (Yes - 1 | No - 2)");
            Scanner YesNoScanner4 = new Scanner(System.in);
            int YesNo4 = YesNoScanner4.nextInt();
            if(YesNo4 == 1) {
                for(int i = 0; i<200;i++) {
                    System.out.println("\n");
                }
                
                
                
                
                
                
                 
            
            
            
            
            
            
            }else {
                System.exit(0);
            }


        }else {
            System.exit(0);
        }


    }


        //new main method 
    
    public void gui() {
         f = new JFrame("Title");
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setResizable(false);
            f.pack();
            f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            f.setSize(618, 640);
            f.setVisible(true);
             String country[]={"India","Aus","U.S.A","England","Newzealand"};
                JComboBox cb=new JComboBox(country);
                cb.setBounds(50, 50,90,20);
                f.add(cb);
                f.setLayout(null);
                f.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    
    public GamePanel(){
        
        
        
        gui();
    
        
         
        
           
         
         
           
        
        
        
    }
 








public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        
        super.paintComponent(g);
        draw(g);
        
        
    }
private void draw(Graphics g) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for(int i=0;i <SCREEN_HEIGHT/UNIT_SIZE;i++) {
        g.drawLine(i*UNIT_SIZE,  0,  i*UNIT_SIZE,  SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        g.drawLine(0, i*UNIT_SIZE, SCREEN_WIDTH, i*UNIT_SIZE);
        }


int fix1 = 30;
 
g.setColor(Color.black);
g.setFont(new Font("BiauKai", Font.BOLD, 20));
FontMetrics metrics = getFontMetrics(g.getFont());
g.drawString(a , (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(a))-580 + fix1 , g.getFont().getSize());
g.drawString(b , (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(b))-560 + fix1 , g.getFont().getSize());
g.drawString(c , (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(c))-540 + fix1 , g.getFont().getSize());
g.drawString(d , (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(d))-520 + fix1 , g.getFont().getSize());
g.drawString(e , (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(e))-500 + fix1 , g.getFont().getSize());
g.drawString(f1 , (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(f1))-480 + fix1 , g.getFont().getSize());
g.drawString(g1 , (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(g1))-460 + fix1 , g.getFont().getSize());
g.drawString(h , (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(h))-440 + fix1 , g.getFont().getSize());
g.drawString(i , (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(i))-420 + fix1 , g.getFont().getSize());
g.drawString(j , (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(j))-400 + fix1 , g.getFont().getSize());
g.drawString(k , (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(k))-380 + fix1 , g.getFont().getSize());
g.drawString(l , (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(l))-365 + fix1 , g.getFont().getSize());
g.drawString(m , (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(m))-340 + fix1 , g.getFont().getSize());
g.drawString(n , (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(n))-320 + fix1 , g.getFont().getSize());
g.drawString(o , (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(o))-300 + fix1 , g.getFont().getSize());
g.drawString(p , (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(p))-280 + fix1 , g.getFont().getSize());
g.drawString(q , (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(q))-260 + fix1 , g.getFont().getSize());
g.drawString(r , (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(r))-240 + fix1 , g.getFont().getSize());
g.drawString(s , (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(s))-220 + fix1 , g.getFont().getSize());
g.drawString(t , (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(t))-200 + fix1 , g.getFont().getSize());
g.drawString(u , (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(u))-180 + fix1 , g.getFont().getSize());
g.drawString(v , (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(v))-160 + fix1 , g.getFont().getSize());
g.drawString(w , (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(w))-140 + fix1 , g.getFont().getSize());
g.drawString(x , (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(x))-120 + fix1 , g.getFont().getSize());
g.drawString(y , (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(y))-100 + fix1 , g.getFont().getSize());
g.drawString(z , (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(z))-80 + fix1 , g.getFont().getSize());
  
g.drawString(a, (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(a))-580 + fix1 , SCREEN_HEIGHT - 560);


//g.drawString(a,40,40);  
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillOval(HeadX, HeadY, UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(BodyX, BodyY, UNIT_SIZE3, UNIT_SIZE + UNIT_SIZE4);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(Arm1X, Arm1Y, UNIT_SIZE3, UNIT_SIZE2);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(Arm2X, Arm2Y, UNIT_SIZE3, UNIT_SIZE2);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(Leg1X, Leg1Y, UNIT_SIZE2, UNIT_SIZE);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(Leg2X, Leg2Y, UNIT_SIZE2, UNIT_SIZE);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(Letter1UnderlineX, Letter1UnderlineY, UNIT_SIZE5, UNIT_SIZE3);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(Letter2UnderlineX, Letter2UnderlineY, UNIT_SIZE5, UNIT_SIZE3);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(Letter3UnderlineX, Letter3UnderlineY, UNIT_SIZE5, UNIT_SIZE3);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(Letter4UnderlineX, Letter4UnderlineY, UNIT_SIZE5, UNIT_SIZE3);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(Letter5UnderlineX, Letter5UnderlineY, UNIT_SIZE5, UNIT_SIZE3);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(Letter6UnderlineX, Letter6UnderlineY, UNIT_SIZE5, UNIT_SIZE3);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(Letter7UnderlineX, Letter7UnderlineY, UNIT_SIZE5, UNIT_SIZE3);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(Letter8UnderlineX, Letter8UnderlineY, UNIT_SIZE5, UNIT_SIZE3);

    
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}



}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: 1. Avoid mixing console input with GUIs; 2. You're not adding the `GamePane` to you window; 3. Avoid `null` layouts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Avoid mixing console input with GUIs;
2. You're not adding the `GamePane` to you window;
3. Avoid `null` layouts

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for some more ideas

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new GamePanel());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                JTextArea rules = new JTextArea(8, 40);
                rules.setWrapStyleWord(true);
                rules.setLineWrap(true);
                rules.append("Rules: Word MUST be less than or equal to 8 characters\n * No SPACES in the word or subject\n * Don't show anyone the word if its your turn for the word\n");
                rules.append("You are about to start. \nDon't show anyone the word and subject your word is based off.");
                rules.append("When writing the word only write ONE letter at a time!");
                rules.append("Write 'done' when you are done writing your word.");

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, rules, "The Rules", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            }
        });
    }

    public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -3919093956447306405L;
        static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 600;
        static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;
        static final int UNIT_SIZE = 100;
        static final int UNIT_SIZE2 = 19;
        static final int UNIT_SIZE3 = 40;
        static final int UNIT_SIZE4 = 20;
        static final int UNIT_SIZE5 = 60;
        // underline ^
        static final int UNIT_SIZE6 = (int) 7.5;
        // break between ___ fix ^
        static final int UNIT_SIZE7 = 0;
        // remove the image
        static final int GAME_UNITS = (SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT) / UNIT_SIZE;
        Random random;
        int HeadX = 400;
        int HeadY = 100;
        int BodyX = 430;
        int BodyY = 180;
        int Arm1X = 400;
        int Arm1Y = 240;
        int Arm2X = 460;
        int Arm2Y = 240;
        int Leg1X = 430;
        int Leg1Y = 300;
        int Leg2X = 451;
        int Leg2Y = 300;
        int Letter1UnderlineX = 0 + UNIT_SIZE6;
        int Letter1UnderlineY = 535;
        int Letter2UnderlineX = 75 + UNIT_SIZE6;
        int Letter2UnderlineY = 535;
        int Letter3UnderlineX = 150 + UNIT_SIZE6;
        int Letter3UnderlineY = 535;
        int Letter4UnderlineX = 225 + UNIT_SIZE6;
        int Letter4UnderlineY = 535;
        int Letter5UnderlineX = 300 + UNIT_SIZE6;
        int Letter5UnderlineY = 535;
        int Letter6UnderlineX = 375 + UNIT_SIZE6;
        int Letter6UnderlineY = 535;
        int Letter7UnderlineX = 450 + UNIT_SIZE6;
        int Letter7UnderlineY = 535;
        int Letter8UnderlineX = 525 + UNIT_SIZE6;
        int Letter8UnderlineY = 535;
        String a = ("a");
        String b = ("b");
        String c = ("c");
        String d = ("d");
        String e = ("e");
        String f1 = ("f");
        String g1 = ("g");
        String h = ("h");
        String i = ("i");
        String j = ("j");
        String k = ("k");
        String l = ("l");
        String m = ("m");
        String n = ("n");
        String o = ("o");
        String p = ("p");
        String q = ("q");
        String r = ("r");
        String s = ("s");
        String t = ("t");
        String u = ("u");
        String v = ("v");
        String w = ("w");
        String x = ("x");
        String y = ("y");
        String z = ("z");
        //
        //        JFrame f;
        //
        //        public static void main(String[] args) {
        //
        //            System.out.println("Welcome to Hang Man!");
        //
        //            Start();
        //
        //            System.out.println("Test");
        //
        //        }
        //
        //        public static void Start() {
        //
        //            Scanner YesNoScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        //            Scanner Letter = new Scanner(System.in);
        //            String[] letters = new String[100];
        //            String ans = "";
        //            int count = 0;
        //
        //            System.out.println("Would you like to play? (Yes - 1 | No - 2)");
        //            int YesNo = YesNoScanner.nextInt();
        //            if (YesNo == 1) {
        //                System.out.println("Rules: Word MUST be less than or equal to 8 characters \n \t No SPACES in the word or subject \n \t Don't show anyone the word if its your turn for the word ");
        //                System.out.println("You are about to start. \nDon't show anyone the word and subject your word is based off.");
        //                System.out.println("When writing the word only write ONE letter at a time!");
        //                System.out.println("Write 'done' when you are done writing your word.");
        //
        //                System.out.println("\n\nChoose a word between 1-8 characters long\n ( ONE LETTER AT A TIME [press enter after every letter])");
        //
        //                do {
        //                    System.out.print("Letter " + (count + 1) + ": ");
        //                    ans = Letter.nextLine();
        //                    if (!ans.equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {
        //                        letters[count] = ans;
        //                        count++;
        //                        if (count == 8) {
        //                            System.out.println("Maximium letters reached");
        //                            ans = ("done");
        //
        //                        }
        //                    }
        //                    String one = letters[0];
        //                } while (!ans.equalsIgnoreCase("done"));
        //
        //                System.out.println("\nYour word is: ");
        //                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        //                    System.out.print(letters[i]);
        //                }
        //
        //                System.out.println(" \nIs this the word you would like? (Yes - 1 | No - 2)");
        //
        //            } else {
        //                System.out.println("You chose to not play. Maybe later :C");
        //                System.exit(0);
        //            }
        //
        //            Scanner YesNoScanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        //            int YesNo2 = YesNoScanner2.nextInt();
        //            if (YesNo2 == 1) {
        //                SubjectWrite();
        //            } else {
        //                Start();
        //            }
        //
        //            new GamePanel();
        //
        //        }
        //
        //        public static void SubjectWrite() {
        //            Scanner Subject = new Scanner(System.in);
        //            String ans = "";
        //
        //            System.out.println("Please choose a subject! (1-10 characters long)");
        //
        //            ans = Subject.nextLine();
        //
        //            System.out.println(" \nIs this the Subject you would like? (Yes - 1 | No - 2)");
        //            System.out.println(ans);
        //
        //            Scanner YesNoScanner3 = new Scanner(System.in);
        //            int YesNo3 = YesNoScanner3.nextInt();
        //            if (YesNo3 == 1) {
        //                System.out.println("Are you ready to play? (Yes - 1 | No - 2)");
        //                Scanner YesNoScanner4 = new Scanner(System.in);
        //                int YesNo4 = YesNoScanner4.nextInt();
        //                if (YesNo4 == 1) {
        //                    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        //                        System.out.println("\n");
        //                    }
        //
        //                } else {
        //                    System.exit(0);
        //                }
        //
        //            } else {
        //                System.exit(0);
        //            }
        //
        //        }

        //        //new main method 
        //        public void gui() {
        //            f = new JFrame("Title");
        //            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //            f.setResizable(false);
        //            f.pack();
        //            f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        //            f.setSize(618, 640);
        //            f.setVisible(true);
        //            f.add(cb);
        //            f.setLayout(null);
        //            f.setVisible(true);
        //        }
        public GamePanel() {
            String country[] = {"India", "Aus", "U.S.A", "England", "Newzealand"};
            JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(country);
            cb.setBounds(50, 50, 90, 20);
            add(cb);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(640, 640);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            draw(g);
        }

        private void draw(Graphics g) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for (int i = 0; i < SCREEN_HEIGHT / UNIT_SIZE; i++) {
                g.drawLine(i * UNIT_SIZE, 0, i * UNIT_SIZE, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
                g.drawLine(0, i * UNIT_SIZE, SCREEN_WIDTH, i * UNIT_SIZE);
            }

            int fix1 = 30;

            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.setFont(new Font("BiauKai", Font.BOLD, 20));
            FontMetrics metrics = getFontMetrics(g.getFont());
            g.drawString(a, (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(a)) - 580 + fix1, g.getFont().getSize());
            g.drawString(b, (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(b)) - 560 + fix1, g.getFont().getSize());
            g.drawString(c, (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(c)) - 540 + fix1, g.getFont().getSize());
            g.drawString(d, (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(d)) - 520 + fix1, g.getFont().getSize());
            g.drawString(e, (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(e)) - 500 + fix1, g.getFont().getSize());
            g.drawString(f1, (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(f1)) - 480 + fix1, g.getFont().getSize());
            g.drawString(g1, (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(g1)) - 460 + fix1, g.getFont().getSize());
            g.drawString(h, (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(h)) - 440 + fix1, g.getFont().getSize());
            g.drawString(i, (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(i)) - 420 + fix1, g.getFont().getSize());
            g.drawString(j, (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(j)) - 400 + fix1, g.getFont().getSize());
            g.drawString(k, (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(k)) - 380 + fix1, g.getFont().getSize());
            g.drawString(l, (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(l)) - 365 + fix1, g.getFont().getSize());
            g.drawString(m, (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(m)) - 340 + fix1, g.getFont().getSize());
            g.drawString(n, (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(n)) - 320 + fix1, g.getFont().getSize());
            g.drawString(o, (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(o)) - 300 + fix1, g.getFont().getSize());
            g.drawString(p, (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(p)) - 280 + fix1, g.getFont().getSize());
            g.drawString(q, (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(q)) - 260 + fix1, g.getFont().getSize());
            g.drawString(r, (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(r)) - 240 + fix1, g.getFont().getSize());
            g.drawString(s, (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(s)) - 220 + fix1, g.getFont().getSize());
            g.drawString(t, (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(t)) - 200 + fix1, g.getFont().getSize());
            g.drawString(u, (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(u)) - 180 + fix1, g.getFont().getSize());
            g.drawString(v, (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(v)) - 160 + fix1, g.getFont().getSize());
            g.drawString(w, (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(w)) - 140 + fix1, g.getFont().getSize());
            g.drawString(x, (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(x)) - 120 + fix1, g.getFont().getSize());
            g.drawString(y, (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(y)) - 100 + fix1, g.getFont().getSize());
            g.drawString(z, (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(z)) - 80 + fix1, g.getFont().getSize());

            g.drawString(a, (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(a)) - 580 + fix1, SCREEN_HEIGHT - 560);

            //g.drawString(a,40,40);  
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillOval(HeadX, HeadY, UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(BodyX, BodyY, UNIT_SIZE3, UNIT_SIZE + UNIT_SIZE4);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(Arm1X, Arm1Y, UNIT_SIZE3, UNIT_SIZE2);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(Arm2X, Arm2Y, UNIT_SIZE3, UNIT_SIZE2);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(Leg1X, Leg1Y, UNIT_SIZE2, UNIT_SIZE);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(Leg2X, Leg2Y, UNIT_SIZE2, UNIT_SIZE);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(Letter1UnderlineX, Letter1UnderlineY, UNIT_SIZE5, UNIT_SIZE3);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(Letter2UnderlineX, Letter2UnderlineY, UNIT_SIZE5, UNIT_SIZE3);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(Letter3UnderlineX, Letter3UnderlineY, UNIT_SIZE5, UNIT_SIZE3);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(Letter4UnderlineX, Letter4UnderlineY, UNIT_SIZE5, UNIT_SIZE3);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(Letter5UnderlineX, Letter5UnderlineY, UNIT_SIZE5, UNIT_SIZE3);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(Letter6UnderlineX, Letter6UnderlineY, UNIT_SIZE5, UNIT_SIZE3);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(Letter7UnderlineX, Letter7UnderlineY, UNIT_SIZE5, UNIT_SIZE3);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(Letter8UnderlineX, Letter8UnderlineY, UNIT_SIZE5, UNIT_SIZE3);

        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }
}
```